# One frame with smearing motion blur

Tags: motion-blur

I have got a fully baked liquid simulation but when rendering i encounter one frame that takes 2 hours to render and had an ugly motion blur smear from movement that the water sim doesn't have in the simulation itself. It does not appear in the previous frame.[image]

edit: It does render faster when using cpu for this shot (using cycles) but everything has a lot of motion blur while the simulation doesnt actually speed up.